# Button redirecting to new jsp page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I was trying to redirect to a n ew jsp page on click of a button like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        var x=$(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();    
        $('#selectedempids').val(x);
        alert("Would submit: " + x);
        loaction.href='ProjectAssigning.jsp';
    });
});
</script>
```

And in html I have something like :

```
<div>

    <h1 align="center">ASSIGN PROJECTS</h1>

    Assign Project To : <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="blah2"></input>
    <br></br>
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedempids" id="selectedempids"></input>
    Project Name : <input type="text" name="projecttitle" id="projecttitle"></input>
    <br></br>

    Project Description : <input type="file" name="description" id="description"></input>

                                 <br></br>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("ValidEmployeeList.jsp", {
            theme: "facebook"
    });
    });
    </script>

</div>
```

But its not getting redirected.Please help me know the reason.

Comment: its  `location.href` not `loaction.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
loaction.href = 'ProjectAssigning.jsp';
```

Use this:

```
window.location.assign('ProjectAssigning.jsp');
```

Comment: And what if instead of button type I want to take submit type to submit the form?

Comment: Then you would have to put the URL in the `action` attribute of the form, as you can't redirect in JS and submit a form at the same time.

Comment: would be grateful if you explain the difference between those two methods